# How can I get the duration between orders from eCommerce data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have typical eCommerce data with several repeat customers, like:

```
customer_id,    order_date
1,              2016.05.01
2,              2016.05.02
3,              2016.05.03
1,              2016.05.04
2,              2016.05.05
1,              2016.05.06
```

And I want output something like:

```
customer_id,        1,          2,          3,
1                   2016.05.01  2016.05.04  2016.05.06
1                   2016.05.02  2016.05.05
1                   2016.05.03
```

And then I can easily get the time between first and second purchase, etc. This is in a mySQL database if there is a sql query that is easy, too

Thanks, Kev

Comment: Do you absolutely want to generate the pivot table as specified in your question or do you want to calculate the number of days between the various orders in a list? SO has lot of questions on pivoting within mysql...

Comment: How many order dates are you intending to return in a single row?

Comment: I don't see any duration in that result

Comment: I know I wasnt very clear in the question, sorry. It is kind of difficult to explain something that I do not fully understand myself, but the answer below worked! Thanks for your attention guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, probably the easiest way is to use variables and conditional aggregation:

```
select customer_id,
       max(case when rn = 1 then order_date end) as order_date_1,
       max(case when rn = 2 then order_date end) as order_date_2,
       max(case when rn = 3 then order_date end) as order_date_3
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = customer_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := customer_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from t cross join
           (select @c := -1, @rn := 1) params
      order by customer_id, order_date desc
     ) t
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is so close to being exactly what I want!! Thanks so much. That sql looks like chinese to me, but it works